# bash command to output the filename which contains specific strings

Tags: bash

I know using `grep` to extract lines matching specific strings. Now I have a bunch of files and I want to know which one contains the specific strings. Is there a way to use bash commands to realize this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

grep -l lists just the file names.

I use this all the time to edit files that contain something

```
vi $(grep -l pattern)  # edit all files containing pattern
```

Please refine your question if that doesn't help enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. `-l` is indeed the operation I need, but if there are more than one patterns, how do I find the file than contains lines which match all the patterns at the same time?

Comment: About multiple patterns combined as if by AND, what you can do is follow the idea above. Get a list of files which match pattern1. Then feed that to another grep -l and so on.  I will make another answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

A refinement was given in a comment under my first answer. There are multiple patterns and the task is to get the list of files which match all of them. Most greps including the GNU one do not implement the regex & intersection operator.  What we can do is first get a list of the files which matches the first pattern. Then feed that list of files to another grep to test against the next pattern and so on.

One approach is with command substitution, which is clumsy and breaks when there are spaces in file names:

```
grep -l pat2 $(grep -l pat1 $(grep -l pat0 *)))

# $(grep -l pat0 *) gets replaced with the names of files matching pat0
# then $(grep -l pat1 <list>) is further refined to include only those matching pat1
# then $(grep -l pat2 <that-list>) is refined once more
```

A solution using xargs addresses some weaknesses in the above solution as well as folding away the nesting. We take the list of files output by each grep -l stage, and convert it into arguments for the next stage using xargs:

```
grep -l pat0 * | xargs grep -l pat1 | xargs grep -l pat2
```

A "compiler" for this can be written, e.g.

```
# the multigrep shell function takes these arguments and produces a pipeline
# like above, then evaluates it using eval.

multigrep pat0 pat1 pat2 *
```

Of course if the patterns are just fixed strings, as insinuated in the original message, add -F to the greps.

Comment: I think this stuff will break if any stage produces an empty list of files, because then xargs will just run grep, and that will expect material from stdin.  The usual /dev/null argument hack can be applied. And of course GNU xargs has --no-run-if-empty.

Comment: GNU grep should have -P (PCRE) which has the regex features you are looking for.